# Requests get other request value in ASHX Handler?

Tags: c#, ashx

I had a job interview and I was asked the following:

Let's say 2 requests were sent **at the exact same** time to an ashx(handler).

First request: `http://www.secretwordHandler.com/?SecretWord=ABRA`

Second request: `http://www.secretwordHandler.com/?SecretWord=KADABRA`

This is the ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomSleepTime = rnd.Next(1000, 10001);

        Thread.Sleep(randomSleepTime);

        string secretWord = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SecretWord"];

        Thread.Sleep(randomSleepTime);

        //What is the secret Word??
        Console.WriteLine(secretWord);

    }
```

Is it possible that the first request will get the result of the second request?

I wasn't sure about answer to it I must admit because the thread sleep I got confused...

Comment: Thread.Sleep only suspends the current thread... context.Current.Request.QueryString["SecretWord"]  ... if the call to ProcessRequest() is not thread safe then it could happen... but just considering this function, I would say no.

Comment: The kicker here looks to be (static) `HttpContext.Current.Request` is being used and not the instanced input context.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen that's  what I thinking, but I couldn't say for sure what will happen...

Comment: If I remember right HttpContext.Current should be threadsafe and it's likely used to try and trick you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that HttpContext.Current is not thread safe, but it doesn't have to. It is explained in this article from Marcus van Houdt: [Understanding the SynchronizationContext in ASP.NET](http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.nl/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html)

To answer your question: it should not be possible that the first request will get the result of the second request.